# Is it legally binding in the UK to declare penalty charge notice issued by the council to the insurer?

Tags: united-kingdom, car, car-insurance, penalty

Does the Penalty Charge Notice (PCN) for a traffic contravention issued by a local council need to be declared to the insurer? Also, does this affect the premium?

Comment: What kind of traffic contravention?

Comment: Driving in a lane reserved for bus all the time

Answer (score 4):

To be certain you'd have to check the policy documents of the specific insurer, or just ask them. However large insurance comparison sites only ask about motoring convictions and penalty points, and a council's penalty charge notice doesn't count as such. So it's unlikely that insurers do want to know this information in general.

There's an overview of the different kinds of penalties here: https://www.rac.co.uk/drive/advice/know-how/fixed-penalty-notices/

A "Fixed Penalty Notice" is issued by the police or equivalent, perhaps via automated enforcement like speed cameras, and does result in a motoring conviction and often penalty points.

A "Penalty Charge Notice" is a civil penalty and won't carry any penalty points on your driving licence.

Comment: Thanks for the article. Good to have that info. However, the article talks about FPN and not PCN. Also, if I asked the insurer, am I not doing what I am trying to avoid if I can?

Comment: The article has a section titled "What's the difference between a Fixed Penalty Notice, Penalty Charge Notice and Parking Charge Notice?". For a particular insurer, you can carefully read your policy documents, but in practice if you phone them and ask if you need to tell them about something, they'll either tell you that you do, or if you don't they won't make any record of it.